# How to convert str List value to int value

Tags: python, string, list, io, integer

The purpose of this exorcise is to use 2 external .txt files both with various integer values
open the files sort them from smallest to largest then output them to a different external .txt file

However I'm having some trouble converting the 2 external input files to integer values so I can
output them in the correct order.

This is what I got so far
please keep in mind ip pretty new to python :)
any help would be appreciated!!!

```
numlist1 = []
numlist2 = []

contents = ""


with open ("numbers1.txt" , "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        contents += line 
        numlist1.append(line)



with open ("numbers2.txt" , "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        contents += line
        numlist2.append(line)

print(numlist1)
print(numlist2)

contents1 = map(int , contents)

print (contents1.sort())
```

```
['1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29']
['2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Python tasks ITP2\L1T18\combined.py", line 25, in <module>
    print (contents1.sort())
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'sort'
PS C:\Users\\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Python tasks ITP2\L1T18>
```

Comment: Could you add the output to the question?  I assume you get an `AttributeError` on the `map.sort()` call, but seeing what `print(numlist1)` and `print(numlist2)` output would be really helpful!

Comment: Im not sure if that helps , im just as new to stackoverflow...

Comment: Nope, that's super helpful because it lets us see what's in the files -- each file is a list of numbers on a single line, separated by spaces.  Based on your code alone I'd have assumed that each number was on its own line!

Comment: are you looking for the function `int( string )` or is it mpre than that?

Answer (score 1):

The `numlist1` and `numlist2` in your code don't really make sense because each file only has one line (which is why printing those lists shows you that each contains a single string).  Rather than iterating over the lines in each file, I'd suggest just calling `f.read()` to append the whole thing to `contents`:

```
contents = ""
for file_name in ("numbers1.txt", "numbers2.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        contents += f.read()
```

Once you've done that, you need to use `split()` to turn the string into a list of smaller strings that you can use `map()` on.

```
numbers = map(int, contents.split())
```

Note that `sort()` sorts a list in place; you can't `.sort()` a `map` object, but you *can* call `sorted()` on it, which returns a sorted list:

```
print(sorted(numbers))
```

You could also make `numbers` a list immediately by either calling `list()` on the `map` object, or using a list comprehension in place of `map()`:

```
numlist = list(map(int, contents.split()))
```

```
numlist = [int(n) for n in contents.split()]
```

Comment: Thank You Samwise!!! I appreciate your help :)   I tried it out ,  it works great!!!